# Norm inequality problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am working on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368518/norms-in-mathbbqi), but using $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ instead of gaussians. I thought it would be a straightforward problem: I pick $|r-a| \leq 1/2$ and $|s-b| \leq 1/2$ then my norm is $$N((r+s\omega) - (a+b\omega)) = N((r-a) + (s-b)\omega),$$ therefore $$(r-a)^2 + (s-b)^2 -(r-a)(s-b) \leq (1/2)^2+(1/2)^2-(1/2)(1/2) = 1/4.$$

But I'm told this is incorrect, that my inequalities reverse direction because of the subtraction. Any help?

Sorry if this is kind of a repost to the previous problem, not sure if this is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want
$|(r-a)^2 + (s-b)^2 -(r-a)(s-b)| \le |r-a|^2 + |s-b|^2 +|r-a|\cdot|s-b| \leq (1/2)^2+(1/2)^2+(1/2)(1/2) = 3/4$

Moreover, you already now that the value you're estimating is non-negative (since it was obtained as $z\cdot\overline z$ for some complex number), so you can omit the absolute value in the first expression and you get
$$0\le (r-a)^2 + (s-b)^2 -(r-a)(s-b) \le \frac34$$

If you chose $r-a=\frac12$ and $s-b=-\frac12$, you can see that the estimate with $\frac14$ instead of $\frac34$ is not true in general.

---

In general $u\le v$ implies $-u\ge -v$.

So if you knew that $(r-a)(s-b)\le \frac14$, you would get the inequality $(r-a)(s-b)\ge-\frac14$. (And this inequality would not help you any further.)

But your assumptions only tell you that $|r-a|\cdot|s-b|\le \frac14$, so you don't know whether $(r-a)(s-b)\le \frac14$ is true and you cannot use this inequality. (Even if you found a way how this inequality might be useful for your proof.)

Comment: Yea thats what Im told I needed, but I'm trying to envision if this alters the conclusion.

Comment: Oh, is that what he meant by changing the direction, if I choose either $r-a$ or $s-b$ to be $-1/2$. I spent all day trying to rationalize that, thinking he meant $\leq$ transitioned to $\geq$